# read "SELECT *" columns into []string in go

Tags: sql, csv, go

I want to write a Go program to dump rows from a database table into a csv file using `SELECT *`.

Go provides the excellent [sql](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql) and [csv](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) apis, but `csv` expects arrays of strings and the `Scan` method in `Rows` "fills" fields according to their types.
As I don't know the table before, I have no idea how many columns there are and what their types are.

It's my first program in Go, so I'm struggling a little.

How do I best read the columns from a `Rows` instance into a `[]string` - and is that the "right" way?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I'm still struggling with the parameters. This is my code, for now I'm using `panic` instead of returning an `error`, but I'm going to change that later. In my test, I'm passing the query result and `os.Stdout`.

```
func dumpTable(rows *sql.Rows, out io.Writer) error {
    colNames, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if rows.Next() {
        writer := csv.NewWriter(out)
        writer.Comma = '\t'
        cols := make([]string, len(colNames))
        processRow := func() {
            err := rows.Scan(cols...)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            writer.Write(cols)
        }
        processRow()
        for rows.Next() {
            processRow()
        }
        writer.Flush()
    }
    return nil
}
```

For this, I get `cannot use cols (type []string) as type []interface {} in function argument` (at the `writer.Write(cols)` line.

I then tested

```
    readCols := make([]interface{}, len(colNames))
    writeCols := make([]string, len(colNames))
    processRow := func() {
        err := rows.Scan(readCols...)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        // ... CONVERSION?
        writer.Write(writeCols)
    }
```

which lead to `panic: sql: Scan error on column index 0: destination not a pointer`.

**UPDATE 2**

I independently arrived at [ANisus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694331/anisus)' solution. This is the code I'm using now.

```
func dumpTable(rows *sql.Rows, out io.Writer) error {
    colNames, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    writer := csv.NewWriter(out)
    writer.Comma = '\t'
    readCols := make([]interface{}, len(colNames))
    writeCols := make([]string, len(colNames))
    for i, _ := range writeCols {
        readCols[i] = &writeCols[i]
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(readCols...)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        writer.Write(writeCols)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    writer.Flush()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: alternative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266044/4031815

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In order to directly `Scan` the values into a `[]string`, you must create an `[]interface{}` slice pointing to each string in your string slice.

Here you have a working example for MySQL (just change the `sql.Open`-command to match your settings):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "database/sql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(localhost:3306)/test?charset=utf8")
    defer db.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to connect", err)
        return
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT 'one' col1, 'two' col2, 3 col3, NULL col4`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to run query", err)
        return
    }

    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get columns", err)
        return
    }

    // Result is your slice string.
    rawResult := make([][]byte, len(cols))
    result := make([]string, len(cols))

    dest := make([]interface{}, len(cols)) // A temporary interface{} slice
    for i, _ := range rawResult {
        dest[i] = &rawResult[i] // Put pointers to each string in the interface slice
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(dest...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to scan row", err)
            return
        }

        for i, raw := range rawResult {
            if raw == nil {
                result[i] = "\\N"
            } else {
                result[i] = string(raw)
            }
        }

        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, great! I just arrived there myself and wanted to post it in an edit. Thanks! That's going to be my answer and I'll upvote it, but I still have a question: I want this to be fast and I'd like to escape string values and convert nil to \N. How do I best include the conversions in my code?

Comment: My solution is far from water tight. It requires the values to be able to be stored in a `string`. E.g. if you get a NULL value from the db, you will have an error because string can't be `nil`. I have updated the answer using []byte and checking for `nil` values.

Comment: You might consider to use `sql.RawBytes` instead of `[]byte`

Comment: I have a table with `varchar`, `int(11)`, and `double` columns.  When trying the code in this answer I get an error: `sql: Scan error on column index 1: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: int64 -> *[]uint8`.  Changing `[][]byte` to `[]sql.RawBytes` produces essentially the same error: `...Scan pair: int64 -> *sql.RawBytes`.  Does the @ANisus comment "able to be stored in a `string`" mean that all columns in the table must be text columns (`varchar`, `text`, etc...)?

Comment: ANisus - do you mind if I use this as a starting point for a toy golang query library?  I'm MIT licensing the overall thing. (https://github.com/dpritchett/go-analyst)

Comment: @DanielJ.Pritchett I don't mind at all! Consider it public domain.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Golang's sql API is really awkwardly designed.

Answer (score 6):

to get the Number of Columns (and also the names) just use the Columns() Function

http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Columns

and as csv can only be a strings, just use a []byte type as dest type for Scanner.
according to docu:

> If an argument has type *[]byte, Scan saves in that argument a copy of
>   the corresponding data. The copy is owned by the caller and can be
>   modified and held indefinitely.

the data will not be transformed into its real type.
and from this []byte you can then convert it to string.

if your are sure your tables only use base types (string, []byte, nil, int(s), float(s), bool) you can directly pass string as dest

but if you use other types like arrays, enums, or so on, then the data cant be transformed to string. but this also depends how the driver handles this types. (some months ago as example, the postgres driver was not able to handle arrays, so he returned always []byte where i needed to transform it by my own)

Comment: Thanks, for now this targets MySQL, so it's base types only.

Comment: Make sure to accept this answer if it works for you (and if there are no better answers)

Comment: I will, but I'm still struggling with the conversion from `[]interface{}` in Scan to `[]string` in Write. Passing `[]string` into Scan didn't compile - I just didn't edit my answer yet. I did upvote, though.

Comment: you need to get the amount of columns first, and then pass that amount of string to Scan

Answer (score 0):

The following code prettily statisfies your requirement, you can get this code at https://gist.github.com/hygull/645c3dc39c69b6b69c06f5ea9deee41f. The table data has been also provided.

```
/**
    {
        "created_on": "26 may 2017",
        "todos": [
            "go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"     
        ],
        "aim": "Reading fname column into []string(slice of strings)"
    }
*/


/* 
mysql> select * from users;
+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------+
| id | fname     | lname    | uname    | email                         | contact      |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | Rishikesh | Agrawani | hygull   | rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com | 917353787704 |
|  2 | Sandeep   | E        | sandeep  | sandeepeswar8@gmail.com       | 919739040038 |
|  3 | Darshan   | Sidar    | darshan  | sidardarshan@gmail.com        | 917996917565 |
|  4 | Surendra  | Prajapat | surendra | surendrakgadwal@gmail.com     | 918385894407 |
|  5 | Mukesh    | Jakhar   | mukesh   | mjakhar.kjahhar@gmail.com     | 919772254140 |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
*/

package main
import "fmt"
import "log"
import (
    _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"   
    "database/sql"
)

func main() {
    // db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "<username>:<password>@tcp(127.0.0.1:<port>)/<dbname>?charset=utf8" )
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "hygull:admin@67@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/practice_db?charset=utf8")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("select fname from users")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    firstnames := []string{}
    for rows.Next() {
        var fname string
        rows.Scan(&fname)
        firstnames = append(firstnames, fname)
    }

    fmt.Println(firstnames)
    db.Close()
}

/* 
[Rishikesh Sandeep Darshan Surendra Mukesh]
*/
```

Comment: Don't think this fits the original question. You are just querying and scanning one known column to []string.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't this be done instead? Simplified below.

```
var tmpErrors string

_ = row.Scan(&tmpErrors)

actualVarHere := strings.Split(tmpErrors, "\n")
```

Would there be a problem or performance issue I am not seeing?