# How do I convert a database row into a struct

Tags: sql, go

Let's say I have a struct:

```
type User struct {
    Name  string
    Id    int
    Score int
}
```

And a database table with the same schema. What's the easiest way to parse a database row into a struct? I've added an answer below but I'm not sure it's the best one.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's one way to do it - just assign all of the struct values manually in the `Scan` function.

```
func getUser(name string) (*User, error) {
    var u User
    // this calls sql.Open, etc.
    db := getConnection()
    // note the below syntax only works for postgres
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1", name).Scan(&u.Id, &u.Name, &u.Score)
    if err != nil {
        return &User{}, err
    } else {
        return &u, nil
    }
}
```

Comment: @eslammostafa at what point this code can have problems with NULL values?

Comment: @deFreitas at score for example, i meant null values that are coming from the database.

Comment: @eslammostafa I understand, this is really a pain

Comment: @deFreitas in the mean time i use sql.NullString and sql.NullInt64 ..etc to handle null values, it's a little extra work though.

Comment: @eslammostafa the problem there is if you use `sql.NullString` and convert the struct to `JSON` then the generated is not friendly, needing to use a `VO` or something like that

Comment: there is a way to fix this, to write a JSONMarshal yourself for your struct, or just use a package called Null it helps with the sql nulls in json, yaml ..etc

Answer (score 116):

Go package tests often provide clues as to ways of doing things. For example, from [`database/sql/sql_test.go`](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql_test.go?h=TestQuery#L252),

```
func TestQuery(t *testing.T) {
    /* . . . */
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT|people|age,name|")
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("Query: %v", err)
    }
    type row struct {
            age  int
            name string
    }
    got := []row{}
    for rows.Next() {
            var r row
            err = rows.Scan(&r.age, &r.name)
            if err != nil {
                    t.Fatalf("Scan: %v", err)
            }
            got = append(got, r)
    }
    /* . . . */
}

func TestQueryRow(t *testing.T) {
    /* . . . */
    var name string
    var age int
    var birthday time.Time
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT|people|age,name|age=?", 3).Scan(&age)
    /* . . . */
}
```

Which, for your question, querying a row into a structure, would translate to something like:

```
var row struct {
    age  int
    name string
}
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT|people|age,name|age=?", 3).Scan(&row.age, &row.name)
```

I know that looks similar to your solution, but it's important to show how to find a solution.

Comment: if the easy way is to manually bind columns to struct fields I'm wondering what's the hard way

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not very convenient especially in case of bigger structs - binding manually to struct properties is complete failure... Using jmoiron/sqlx or some other libraries is more efficient...

Comment: i keep getting back nothing from rows.Scan(). all the vars are set to be empty.

Comment: What the heck is the pipe syntax here?  "SELECT|people" ? I don't see any reference to that in the godocs.

Comment: Had the same WTF moment as Brian. Turns out its a fake driver they made purely for testing sql/database (https://golang.org/src/database/sql/fakedb_test.go) I was really hoping I could use it for new code!

Answer (score 76):

I recommend [github.com/jmoiron/sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx).

From the README:

> sqlx is a library which provides a set of extensions on go's standard
>   `database/sql` library.  The sqlx versions of `sql.DB`, `sql.TX`,
>   `sql.Stmt`, et al. all leave the underlying interfaces untouched, so
>   that their interfaces are a superset on the standard ones.  This makes
>   it relatively painless to integrate existing codebases using
>   database/sql with sqlx.
>
> Major additional concepts are:
>
> - Marshal rows into structs (with embedded struct support), maps, and slices
> - Named parameter support including prepared statements
> - `Get` and `Select` to go quickly from query to struct/slice

---

The README also includes a code snippet demonstrating scanning a row into a struct:

```golang
type Place struct {
    Country       string
    City          sql.NullString
    TelephoneCode int `db:"telcode"`
}
// Loop through rows using only one struct
place := Place{}
rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT * FROM place")
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.StructScan(&place)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    } 
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", place)
}
```

Note that we didn't have to manually map each column to a field of the struct.  sqlx has some default mappings for struct fields to database columns, as well as being able to specify database columns using tags (note the `TelephoneCode` field of the `Place` struct above).   You can read more about that in [the documentation](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#mapping).

Comment: Old question, but this can help someone in the future: http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#safety

Answer (score 7):

```
rows, err := connection.Query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `email` FROM `users`")

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

for rows.Next() {
    var user User

    if err := rows.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Username, &user.Email); err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

    users = append(users, user)
}
```

[Full example](http://simpledev.su/2017/10/18/golang-mysql-poluchenie-kollekcii-zapisey/)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a library just for that: [scany](https://github.com/georgysavva/scany).

You can use it like that:

```golang
type User struct {
    Name  string
    Id    int
    Score int
}

// db is your *sql.DB instance
// ctx is your current context.Context instance

// Use sqlscan.Select to query multiple records.
var users []*User
sqlscan.Select(ctx, db, &users, `SELECT name, id, score FROM users`)

// Use sqlscan.Get to query exactly one record.
var user User
sqlscan.Get(ctx, db, &user, `SELECT name, id, score FROM users WHERE id=123`)
```

It's well documented and easy to work with.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

Answer (score 1):

there's package just for that: [sqlstruct](https://github.com/kisielk/sqlstruct)

unfortunately, last time I checked it did not support embedded structs (which are trivial to implement yourself - i had a working prototype in a few hours).

just committed the changes I made to [sqlstruct](https://github.com/a-palchikov/sqlstruct)

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers here, I would like to add an SQL library I wrote just for tackling this issue of how complex it is to do a simple query on the most used Golang libraries; its called [KSQL](https://github.com/vingarcia/ksql) (not the Kafka one, the K stands for KISS or Keep It Stupid Simple).

Using it you could scan a user into a struct like this:

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/vingarcia/ksql"
    "github.com/vingarcia/ksql/adapters/kpgx"
)

type User struct {
    Id    int    `ksql:"id"`
    Name  string `ksql:"name"`
    Score int    `ksql:"score"`
}

// Just a simple struct containing the table name and
// the name of the ID column or columns:
var UsersTable = ksql.NewTable("users", "id")

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=UTC"
    db, err := kpgx.New(ctx, dsn, ksql.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    // Lets insert a user so the query below has something to return:
    err = db.Insert(ctx, UsersTable, &User{
        Name:  "SomeUser",
        Score: 42,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var user User
    err = db.QueryOne(ctx, &user, "FROM users WHERE name = $1", "SomeUser")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", user) // {Id:1 Name:SomeUser Score:42}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use : 
[go-models-mysql](https://github.com/eehsiao/go-models-mysql)
[sqlbuilder](https://github.com/eehsiao/sqlbuilder)

```golang
val, err = m.ScanRowType(row, (*UserTb)(nil))
```

or the full code

```golang
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    lib "github.com/eehsiao/go-models-lib"
    mysql "github.com/eehsiao/go-models-mysql"
)

// MyUserDao : extend from mysql.Dao
type MyUserDao struct {
    *mysql.Dao
}

// UserTb : sql table struct that to store into mysql
type UserTb struct {
    Name       sql.NullString `TbField:"Name"`
    Id         int            `TbField:"Id"`
    Score      int            `TbField:"Score"`
}

// GetFirstUser : this is a data logical function, you can write more logical in there
// sample data logical function to get the first user
func (m *MyUserDao) GetFirstUser() (user *User, err error) {

    m.Select("Name", "Id", "Score").From("user").Limit(1)
    fmt.Println("GetFirstUser", m.BuildSelectSQL().BuildedSQL())
    var (
        val interface{}
        row *sql.Row
    )

    if row, err = m.GetRow(); err == nil {
        if val, err = m.ScanRowType(row, (*UserTb)(nil)); err == nil {
            u, _ := val.(*UserTb)

            user = &User{
                Name:       lib.Iif(u.Name.Valid, u.Nae.String, "").(string),
                Id:         u.Id,
                Score:      u.Score,
            }
        }
    }
    row, val = nil, nil

    return
}
```