# Is it possible to retrieve a column value by name using GoLang database/sql

Tags: sql, go

All of the examples I've seen for using `sql.Row`, access return values from queries by **position**:`sql.Rows.scan()` requires a correctly typed variable correctly **positioned** in the `scan()` arguments corresponding to the appropriate column, to retrieve each column value returned, such as in the following example:

[**Example Based on GoDocs (with small mod):**](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-examples)

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name,age FROM users WHERE age>=50")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for rows.Next() {
    var name string
    var age int

    if err := rows.Scan(&name,&age); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

`&name` and `&age` must be positioned correctly (columns 0 and 1) for Rows.Scan() to retrieve the correct values with the correct types.

Over my years of development for production systems, I have come to studiously avoid this practice because it's not robust: A database change in the layout of the columns will easily break your code if it's based on column positions.

It is far more robust to use **column names** for retrieving values - this insulates you from changes to the database that add or remove columns that screw up your position based code. For example, in Delphi and C#, all dataSets, including columns returning values from queries, support `FieldByName('age').asInteger` or `fields['age'].value,` etc.

Any way to accomplish this in Go? If not, this is a big drawback in Go database support and a serious disappointment - not at all safe, as mentioned.

***Edit:***

Also *(perhaps this is a new question)*: The examples I've seen seem to require you to retrieve all the columns returned by the query, or the positions of the columns will be skewed.

Suppose there is  utility query in a locked-down database that I cannot modify or add to, and it retrieves several columns, but I only need one of them for my current task. Based on the current `sql.Rows.Scan()` model, I have to retrieve all the values from the query in my application code, even though I don't need them, whereas if I could query `"columnByName"` that would not be necessary - I could just bring into my application code the data I need. Any work-around for this?

Comment: With the [column names](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Columns), a utility function giving you an access by column name wouldn't be hard to implement.

Comment: @dystroy - AFAIK, not really: I was thinking using a map with the column names as keys and column values as values. But the underlying scan() call would still rely on position and break if the DB schema changed. Maybe you are thinking of something else?

Comment: Getting the field by name does not really protect you from all database changes. Some integration tests for your code would be more robust.

Comment: @alpe1 - not sure what your point is here...

Comment: @ComeAndGo I have a function I like to implement whenever I'm working with running mysql queries that basically packages the data into a slice of maps of strings to strings ([]map[string]string). Each slice is the equivalent of a row, the map key string is the column name and the map value string is the column value for that row. Here is a simple playground to demonstrate how it works and share the packageData function code: http://play.golang.org/p/ctZYCn9EI9

Comment: @Verran - _the data into a slice of maps of strings to strings ([]map[string]string). Each slice is the equivalent of a row_ - Yes,that's exactly along the lines I was thinking, as per my comment above. I will check out your code. Also see edit to question...

Comment: @Verran -[**sqlx**](http://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)  looks like it does the kinds of things I'm interested in...

Comment: Your example *already is* using "column names for retrieving values". The `select` uses column names without regard to the ordering of those columns in the database. You are "insulate[d] from changes to the database that add or remove columns" as long as the column names still exist. The scan positional arguments only need to match the select query which are usually very close in together in the code and easily kept in sync when changes are made.

Comment: i.e. you appear to be blindly following a rule without *fully* understanding why and when it's applicable. IMO, it's only relevant if you were to foolishly use `SELECT * FROM …` and then do positional scanning.

Comment: @DaveC _it's only relevant if you were to foolishly use SELECT * FROM …_ : ??? . The example does not use `SELECT * FROM`. The practice I follow was learned from years of experience working in team environments on complex systems and was an enforced rule in many cases: **"Always use column names. Do not rely on column positions."** It's easy to understand on large teams with large systems:DBA adds a column in the middle of a table and it breaks all your code **without** an error message, instead of something like _column 'age' not found'_ .

Comment: @DaveC _easily kept in sync when changes are made_ - you downvoted but completely missed the point of the question, which is **I don't want to have to worry about keeping them in sync.** That's **not** how you write safe, production worthy code. You want to write code that's robust: **It's doesn't have to be kept in sync.** You're also making assumptions about application architecture - how my code might be structured, and ignoring the fact that in team development, someone may not be at all familiar with the code in question.

Comment: This alternative is my favorite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266044/4031815

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this without having to manually match up the column positions. There are some third-party libraries you can use to do this, such as [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) or [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp). I would recommend sticking with one of these instead of rolling your own.

Named matching does have a slight penalty. Named matching is no different than matching up the column positions yourself. It just does this work for you at runtime - possibly on every query execution. This is true in any other language.

Why at runtime? The query is written as a string. It has to be parsed to determine the position.

If you were to make your own library, how do you do this on your own?

- [Rows.Columns](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Columns) to get column names and positions.
- Passing a slice of pointers `[]interface{}` to [Rows.Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) to get the values.
- [reflect.Value](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) and [Value.Addr](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Addr) to get a pointer to the destination value.
- [Value.FieldByName](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) to get the `Value` of a struct field if you want to map to struct fields.

Ok, so lets see how this works.

```
type Person struct {
    Id int
    Name string
}
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, name FROM person;")
if err != nil {
    // handle err
    log.Fatal(err)
}
columnNames, err := rows.Columns() // []string{"id", "name"}
if err != nil {
    // handle err
    log.Fatal(err)
}
people = make([]Person, 0, 2)
for rows.Next() {
    person := Person{}
    // person == Person{0, ""}
    pointers := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    // pointers == `[]interface{}{nil, nil}`
    structVal := reflect.ValueOf(person)
    for i, colName := range columnNames {
        fieldVal := structVal.FieldByName(strings.Title(colName))
        if !fieldVal.IsValid() {
            log.Fatal("field not valid")
        }
        pointers[i] = fieldVal.Addr().Interface()
    }
    // pointers == `[]interface{}{&int, &string}`
    err := rows.Scan(pointers...)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // person == Person{1, "John Doe"}
    people = append(people, person)
}
```

Comment: how is this not natively supported?

Comment: Column names are dynamic. Go is statically compiled. So you have to match up the names at runtime. There are libraries that do this for you. This answer shows how it is done.

Comment: column names are never dynamic, you'd have to recompile the code anyway to change your sql stmt/column names. I'm just surprised at how much of a PITA it is in Go atm. even with sqlx, which is awesome.

Comment: Column names are stored in a string var, which can be populated externally without recompile. That makes them not static. A struct field name is static. Changing those require recompile.

Comment: even in such extreme cases accessing the results by column names instead of column position is the only thing that would make sense

Answer (score 2):

The only sane & clean way to do this is to use: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

Let say you have a Place struct:

```
type Place struct {
    Country       string
    City          sql.NullString
    TelephoneCode int `db:"telcode"`
}
```

You scan it easily:

```
rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT * FROM place")
for rows.Next() {
    var p Place
    err = rows.StructScan(&p)
}
```

More info: http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different approach to the data would help, like something like this:

```
func GetFieldValues(res *sql.Rows) []string {
    m, err := res.ColumnTypes()
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    var (
        //i    int = 0
        mLen int = len(m)
    )
    if res.Next() {
        mValStr := make([]sql.NullString, mLen)
        mVal := make([]any, mLen)
        for i := range mVal {
            mVal[i] = &mValStr[i]
        }

        res.Scan(mVal...) //super

        mmVal := make([]string, mLen)
        for i := 0; i < mLen; i++ {
            if mValStr[i].Valid {
                mmVal[i] = mValStr[i].String
            } else {
                mmVal[i] = "" // empty string is nil in this context --> see func IsNull
            }
        }
        mVal = nil // Free allocated mem
        return mmVal

    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*/*
*

- GetPointersRowSQL uses, generate automatic fileds
- people = model.Suspicious{}
- for row.Next() {
- pointer := util.GetPointersRowSQL(row, &people)
- if pointer != nil {
  err = row.Scan(pointer...)
  }

  }
  return people, err

- 

**/

func GetPointersRowSQL(rows *sql.Rows, val any) (p []interface{}) {

```
columnNames, err := rows.Columns()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
nro := len(columnNames)
pointers := make([]interface{}, nro)

/*for j, colName := range columnNames {
    columnNames[j] = strings.Title(colName)
}*/

structVal := reflect.ValueOf(val).Elem()

for i, colName := range columnNames {
    fieldVal := structVal.FieldByName(strings.Title(colName))
    //fieldVal := structVal.FieldByName(colName)
    if !fieldVal.IsValid() {
        log.Println("field not valid  " + colName)
        return nil
    }
    pointers[i] = fieldVal.Addr().Interface()
}
return pointers
```

}

Comment: maybe help this code

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?** Please also evaluate your formatting.