# Scanning large rows into structs in Go

Tags: json, database, go, struct

I'm working with a database which has yet to be normalized, and this table contains records with over 40 columns.

The following is my Go code for (attempting) to scan the records into a large struct:

```
type Coderyte struct {
  ID int `json:"id"`
  EmrID int `json:"emr_id"`
  DftID int `json:"dft_id"`

  Fix int `json:"fix"`
  ReportDate string `json:"report_date"` // Time?
  Patient string `json:"patient"`
  ... // etc
}
func ReadCoderyte(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM coderyte")
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(res, "Error querying database", 500)
  }
  defer rows.Close()

  // Convert rows into a slice of Coderyte structs
  coderytes := make([]*Coderyte, 0)
  for rows.Next() {
    coderyte := new(Coderyte)
    err := rows.Scan(&coderyte) // Expected 42 columns
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
      http.Error(res, "Error converting coderyte object", 500)
    }
    coderytes = append(coderytes, coderyte)
  }
```

When I call this code, `Scan` complains that it "expected 42 destination arguments, not 1". My understanding is that I would need to address every single field in this large struct, inside of the scan call, ie `Scan(&coderyte.ID, &coderyte.EmrID, etc)`

My searches have only yielded [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265463/how-do-i-convert-a-database-row-into-a-struct-in-go), where the suggested answer is to use `sqlx`. I'm trying to avoid using a third-party tool if I don't need it.

My question boils down to: **Is there a way to convert a large database record into a struct without specifying every single field?**.

I should also note that the ultimate goal of this function is to return a JSON array of objects, but I did not include that part of the code because I feel it is not important. If there is a way to bypass `Scan` and return JSON, that would be an appreciated answer as well.

Comment: Short answer: no.
Long answer: I also recommend sqlx. The standard library does not support unmarshalling into a struct.

Comment: Same recommendation from me as well.

Comment: Yep it is not supported, but if you still want to use standard sql package I would recommend to read http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

Comment: RE: The second part of your question: I made a little package I use all over the place for exactly this. It's pretty straightforward if you want to check it out, I threw it up in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/heyimalex/075bb442af0ecbf3e5f561336101e4f7

Comment: @AlexGuerra it may be annoying to have to make and tag structs for `sqlx` but utilizing the type-safety of that method has its advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ultimate goal of this function is to return a JSON array of objects

It sounds like you could byass the struct entirely then, and instead scan into a `map[string]interface{}`, and do it all pretty dynamically:
You could do something like this:

```
rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM coderyte") 
cols, _ := rows.Columns()
store := []map[string]interface{}
for rows.Next() {
    columns := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    for i, _ := range columns {
        columnPointers[i] = &columns[i]
    }

    if err := rows.Scan(columnPointers...); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i, colName := range cols {
        val := columnPointers[i].(*interface{})
        m[colName] = *val
    }
    store = append(store, m)        
}
js, _ := json.Marshal(store)
fmt.Println(string(js))
```

Now, obviously you could also convert it to a struct, since you could take the json and do `json.Unmarshal`, but given your use case that seems like a pointless extra step.

```
js, _ := json.Marshal(store)
structs := []Coderyte{}
json.Unmarshal(js, &structs)
```

All that being said, you should probably just use sqlx - they probably do way cleverer things and do it way more efficiently.

Comment: I just spoke with my boss, who revealed he has been using `sqlx` in his tinkerings with the same data. I'll be trying this solution, because for now I only want the JSON representation of the data, but I will probably move to `sqlx` per the other comments and your recommendation. Thanks!