# Can Go's Rows.Scan ignore fields from SQL query

Tags: go, cockroachdb

The [`Rows.Scan`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) method takes as many parameters as there are columns in the SQL query.

As the query being executed is `SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table` I cannot omit any column which I don't require (or can I?).

Is there any way to ignore some fields from the query result set which is not required?

Below is my code:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " + r.Name)
DieIf(err)
//var field, dataType, ignoreMe1, ignoreMe2, ignoreMe3 string
var field, dataType string
for rows.Next() {
                    //This Place
                    //   |
                    //   V
    if err := rows.Scan(&field, &dataType); err != nil {
        DieIf(err)
    }
    r.Attributes[field] = Attribute{
        Name:       field,
        DataType:   dataType,
        Constraint: false,
    }
}
```

error:
`sql: expected 5 destination arguments in Scan, not 2`

Comment: you can not ignore, if the selected fields count 5 then you have to pass 5 variable to scan in `scan()` , if you want scan only two values then you can write query like `select field, type from <tableName>`

Comment: I cannot pass field names in SHOW COLUMNS QUERY.

Comment: so you can use `[]interface' to get that values and use according to your requirement.

Comment: i've attached code below, try this one, hope you will get your point.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

So here I'm with one solution for you, try this one to get `field` and `type` from query.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "database/sql"
)

func main() {

    db, _ := sql.Open(
        "postgres",
        "user=postgres dbname=demo password=123456")

    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM tableName;")

    columns, _ := rows.Columns()
    count := len(columns)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    valuePtr := make([]interface{}, count)

    for rows.Next() {

        for i, _ := range columns {
            valuePtr[i] = &values[i]
        }

        rows.Scan(valuePtr...)

        for i, col := range columns {

            var v interface{}

            val := values[i]

            b, ok := val.([]byte)

            if (ok) {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }

            fmt.Println(col, v)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why fetch all rows when you need only 1? use `SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 1;` instead ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010085/11004152) suggested, sqlx could be a good choice.

I personally use db.Unsafe() to ignore unwanted fields.

```
type MyTable struct {
    // list the fields you want here
    Name   string `db:"name"`
    Field1 string `db:"field1"`
}

db := try(sqlx.ConnectContext(context.Background(), "mysql",
    fmt.Sprintf("root:@tcp(%s:%d)/?charset=utf8mb4&timeout=3s", host, port)))
db = db.Unsafe()

rows := try(db.Queryx("select * from mytable"))
for rows.Next() {
    myTable := MyTable{}
    rows.StructScan(&myTable)
}
```