# Can't scan queried data into variable

Tags: go

my intention is to scan queried data into a variable for further use. When printing u I get an empty struct, what am  I doing wrong?

```
type User struct {
Username string `db:"username"`
Email    string `db:"email"`
Password string `db:"password"`
```

}

```
func SearchUserInDB(db *sql.DB, userormail string) error {
var u User
err := db.QueryRow(`
            SELECT 
               *
            FROM 
                users
            WHERE username = $1`, userormail).Scan(&u)
fmt.Println(u)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
return nil
```

}

Comment: try to scan into primitive types and initialising your `User` struct with the values.

Comment: Scan to the individual fields: `Scan(&u.UserName, &u.Email, &u.Password)`.   Adjust the order of the fields to match the order of the database columns.

Comment: FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265463/how-do-i-convert-a-database-row-into-a-struct